# Is there any code which needs to be included for deleting the nodes in Java Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

Write a Java program to move the last element of the linked list in the front and rest of the element by one position, and then print the modified linked list.

NOTE: Remember you cannot use the LinkedList java class and its methods, you have to make your own LinkedList class and methods.

I have written the code to move the last node to the first but ii'm not able to delete the node whichever I wanted.

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class LinkedList {
        Node head;
    class Node
    {
        int data ;
        Node next;
        Node(int a )
        {
            data = a ;
            next = null;

        }
    }

    void movefront()
    {
        if(head == null || head.next == null)
            return;

        Node secLast = null;
        Node last = head;

        while(last.next!= null)
        {
            secLast = last;
            last = last.next;
        }
        secLast.next=null;
        last.next = head;
        head = last;
    }
void deleteNode(int key) 
    { 
        // Store head node 
        Node temp = head, prev = null; 

        // If head node itself holds the key to be deleted 
        if (temp != null && temp.data == key) 
        { 
            head = temp.next; // Changed head 
            return; 
        } 

        // Search for the key to be deleted, keep track of the 
        // previous node as we need to change temp.next 
        while (temp != null && temp.data != key) 
        { 
            prev = temp; 
            temp = temp.next; 
        }     

        // If key was not present in linked list 
        if (temp == null) return; 

        // Unlink the node from linked list 
        prev.next = temp.next; 
    } 

    public void push (int new_data)

    {
        Node new_node = new Node(new_data);
        new_node.next= head;
        head = new_node;

    }

    void printList()
    {
        Node temp = head;
        while(temp!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(temp.data + " ");
            temp = temp.next;
        } System.out.println();
    }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


     System.out.println("Number of integers to be enetered in the list:");
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();
     Integer n= sc.nextInt();
     Integer arr[]=new Integer[n];
     System.out.println("Insert the elements of your array");
     for(int i=0; i<=arr.length; i++)
     {
         n= sc.nextInt();

         llist.push(n);

        }

     System.out.println(" Linked list before moving last to front : " );
     llist.printList();
    llist.movefront();
llist.deleteNode(2);
     System.out.println(" Linked list after moving from front to last : ");
    llist.printList();
    }

    }
```

Comment: OK... so what's preventing you from deleting a node? Does an auntie come and shout at you when you try to write the code that deletes it? Does your computer burst into flames? What seems to be the problem? Describe what you've tried and how it fails. The code you posted doesn't even demonstrate an attempt. Also, clarify what you mean by "delete." Do you want to create a method that allows a user to choose the node to delete, or do you just want to orphan a node and let the garbage collector deal with it?

Comment: Made necessary modifications can you please help me out for getting the correct output.

Comment: @ManasaReddy you have various mistakes in current program. 1 You are reading one more input from user since i<=arr.length in main. Secondly you are inserting new element in starting of linked list instead it should be added at the end

Comment: To "delete" a node, all you have to do is make the `next` field of the preceding node refer to the following node, and the target node is gone from your linked list. You don't have to include any special code to get rid of it -- removing the reference is sufficient. You're not going to learn anything if I write this code for you, so give it a try on your own.

Comment: @ManasaReddy How do you want deletion operation. can you please explain. I mean which node do you want to delete. Is is first or last or any other node????

Comment: I want to delete the 1st node

Comment: @ManasaReddy I have added an explanation in my answer. let me know if it works for you or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
public class LinkedList {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    Node head;
    class Node
    {
        int data ;
        Node next;
        Node(int a )
        {
            data = a ;
            next = null;

        }
    }

    void movefront()
    {
        if(head == null || head.next == null)
            return;

        Node secLast = null;
        Node last = head;

        while(last.next!= null)
        {
            secLast = last;
            last = last.next;
        }
        secLast.next=null;
        last.next = head;
        head = last;
    }

    public void push(int new_data)
    {
        Node new_node = new Node(new_data);
        new_node.next= null;

        if(head == null) {
            head = new_node;
            return;
        }
        Node last_Node = head;
        while(last_Node.next != null) {
            last_Node = last_Node.next;
        }
        last_Node.next = new_node;
    }

    void printList()
    {
        Node temp = head;
        while(temp != null)
        {
            System.out.println(temp.data + " ");
            temp = temp.next;
        } System.out.println();
    }

    private void delete() {

        Node current_Node = head;
        if(current_Node == null) {
            System.out.println("no element in list to be deleted");
            return;
        }

        head = current_Node.next;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Number of integers to be entered in the list:");

        LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();
        Integer n= sc.nextInt();
        Integer arr[]=new Integer[n];
        System.out.println("Insert the elements of your array: ");
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        {
            n= sc.nextInt();
            llist.push(n);
        }

        System.out.println("Linked list before moving last to front: " );
        llist.printList();
        llist.movefront();
        System.out.println("Linked list after moving from front to last: ");
        llist.printList();

        System.out.println("Deleting first element from the list: ");
        llist.delete();
        llist.printList();
    }

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Explanation:**

1. Updated `for(int i=0; i<=arr.length; i++)` to `for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)` in `main` method as index start from `0` so it should go till `arr.length-1` hence `i<arr.length`.
2. Updated `push` method. New node is inserted at the end of the linkedlist but in your code it was acting as `stack`.
3. Added `delete` method to remove first `node`. If `head` is null in that case list is empty hence no element can be removed from the list. If it contains element then `head` will point to `current_Node.next;`

Comment: Absolutely correct what if we want to delete which ever node we want to delete what modification we have to do .suppose if we give input 5 7 32 81 47 78 Output should be like 78 7 32 81 47

Comment: @ManasaReddy in that you need to tell delete method which node to delete. I mean to say that you will need to tell index of node which you want to delete from the list

Comment: I have given the index on node but it showing the following error The method delete() in the type Linkedlist is not applicable for the argument types(int)System.out.println("Deleting first element from the list: ");
         llist.delete(2);
         llist.printList();

Comment: It won't work untill you provide its implementation in delete method